# Query Across Multiple Tables to Join Data

Tags: ms-access

I have multiple access tables with a field called Attribute and a field called Source.  I am wanting to run a query that lists all attributes across all access tables and also list each Source that the particular attribute shows up.  I am assuming this is two separate queries.  I am at a loss of how to write this particular query.

Table1
Attribute | Source
    Mem             | Mem
    Mem.Address             | Mem
    Mem.Last             | Mem
    Mem.First             | Mem

Table2
Attribute | Source
    Mem             | Dep
    Dep.Address             | Dep
    Dep.Last             | Dep
    Dep.First             | Dep

Table3
Attribute | Source
    Prov             | Prov
    Prov.Address             | Prov
    Prov.Last             | Prov
    Prov.First             | Prov
    Mem            | Prov

ExpectedResultsQuery
Attribute | Source
    Mem             | Mem, Dep & Prov
    Mem.Address             | Mem
    Mem.Last             | Mem
    Mem.First             | Mem
    Dep.Address             | Dep
    Dep.Last             | Dep
    Dep.First             | Dep
    Prov             | Prov
    Prov.Address             | Prov
    Prov.Last             | Prov
    Prov.First             | Prov

Comment: Please [provide](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample data and expected result. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: I made the update for the sample and sample expected results.

Comment: This is super-hard to read. Please use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ and format the result as code.

Answer (score 1):

A UNION query can combine the tables for first stage.

```
SELECT Attribute, Source, "T1" AS Src FROM Table1
UNION SELECT Attribute, Source, "T2" FROM Table2
UNION SELECT Attribute, Source, "T3" FROM Table3
```

Second query could use first query as source for a VBA function that will concatenate Source values to each Attribute. One such function at http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html.

MEM appears to be only Attribute with multiple Source. VBA function is a lot of processing for such minimal result and can perform slowly on large dataset. Could instead just build a report that groups by Attribute.

Alternative to concatenating Source values to single string is a CROSSTAB query using UNION query as source:

```
TRANSFORM First(TableUNION.Source) AS FirstOfSource
SELECT TableUNION.Attribute
FROM TableUNION
GROUP BY TableUNION.Attribute
PIVOT DCount("*","TableUNION","Attribute='" & [Attribute] & "' AND  Source<'" & [Source] & "'")+1;
```